# Problems with the "edit" method in TableView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, kotlin

I'm learn kotlin and javafx. I'm trying to set up an event.

This java code works:

```
tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
       TablePosition<?, ?> pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
       if (pos != null && event.getCode().isLetterKey()) {
          tableView.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
       }
});
```

The same code in kontlin(not work):

```
class DynamicTableView : Application() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        val tableView = TableView<ObservableList<String>>()
        tableView.setEditable(true)
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true)


        tableView.setOnKeyPressed { event ->
            val pos = tableView.focusModel.focusedCell
            if (pos != null && event.code.isLetterKey) {
                tableView.edit(pos.row, pos.tableColumn)
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        primaryStage.show();


    }


    companion object {

        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            launch(DynamicTableView::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Kotlin: tableView.edit(pos.row, pos.tableColumn) method tableColumn return the wrong type.

Verbatim: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is TableColumn <Any!, Any!>! but TableColumn<ObservableList<String>!, *>! was expected

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: So what's line 41?

Comment: tableView.edit(pos.row, pos.tableColumn) method tableColumn returned an invalid type.

Comment: `tableView.edit(pos.row, tableView.columns.get(pos.column))` is type safe.

Comment: Thank you. Everything work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need

```
    tableView.setOnKeyPressed { event ->
        val pos = tableView.focusModel.focusedCell
        if (pos != null && event.code.isLetterKey) {
            tableView.edit(pos.row, tableView.columns[pos.column])
        }
    }
```